# Correlation time (non linear) in ising model (3D)

Tags: ising-model, correlation-functions

I am currently implementing the classical Ising model (3D) for a demonstration. 
I use the common implementation of metropolis,teller,teller ("Metropolis"-algorithm) and measure certain quantities. Usually it's fine to take 10*systemsize iterations (in a single spin flip mc) until equilibration. But i want to use the autocorrelation for the updates AFTER equilibration (which is easy to determine) and the Non-linear correlation time to find the adequate equilibration time for a system (both to receive uncorrelated samples).
The nl correlation time can be gained by taking the slope of the log-plot of the non linear correlation function, which is defined by $$\phi_A^{nl} (t) = \frac{\left< A(t) \right> -\left< A(\infty)\right>}{\left< A(t_0) \right> -\left< A(\infty)\right>} $$ hence i would calculate e.g. the averages of the energy or magnetisation at different times and should be done? Now i face the trouble, that $A(\infty)$ is the actual equilibrated system. I wonder if there is either a better way to find the non linear correlation time or a way to determine the equilibrated value without running the simulation for a long time?

Comment: Could you provide some reference for this non-linear correlation time? I've never heard about it and don't really understand the equation you put there. I guess you know how to calculate the normal autocorrelation function $\phi_A(\Delta t)$, which is just the [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) between $A(t)$ and $A(t+\Delta t)$?

Comment: @RobertRüger: Yes, indeed the autocorrelation function could be used for a better estimate of the dropped samples between the measurements (for certain temperature). You can for example find it in the book "Monte Carlo Simulation in Statistical Physics - An Introduction“ (Kurt Binder, Dieter W. Heermann) fifth edition - page 34 you will find the mentioned equation.

Comment: Had a look at the book you mentioned. For a straightforward implementation of it you would indeed need to run your simulation several times to do the average $\langle A(t) \rangle$ and once for a really long time to determine $\langle A(\infty) \rangle$. Are you really interested in the non-linear correlation time itself or are you just looking for a practical way to determine how long you need to equilibrate?

Comment: @RobertRüger Actually i am looking for the practical way. I know about the common way of e.g. just taking (3-10)*N [depending on the author, e.g. compare Landau "Survey of comp. physics" and Pang "Introduction to comp. physics"] equilibration steps. But i was hoping for a more - well - accurate solution.But maybe it's just best to keep it simple a stick with the constant numbers for equilibration...